# MomentJS diff is adding an hour

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am doing this

```js
const currentCETTime = moment.tz('2020-03-18 15:58:38', 'Europe/Madrid');
const limitCETTime = moment.tz('2020-03-18 18:00:00', 'Europe/Madrid');
console.log('current',currentCETTime.format('HH:mm:ss'));
console.log('limit', limitCETTime.format('HH:mm:ss'));
const seconds = Math.abs(limitCETTime.diff(currentCETTime) / 1000);
console.log('hours', (seconds / 60) / 60);
const rem = moment(seconds * 1000);
console.log('diff', moment(rem).tz('Europe/Madrid').format('HH:mm'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.min.js"></script>
```

And I am getting a wrong difference:

[image]

I should get a difference of 2:01 hours instead of 03:01

Comment: I converted your code into a code block that you can execute in the question. I also removed any aliasing you had done with `momentTZ` as that was not defined. If the changes do not produce your expected result please further edit it as necessary but do try to keep it so that it is a code snippit you can execute.

Comment: Thank you Igor, I do not know how to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need hour and second, then no need to use timezone. You can call utc and then format. Check code below.

```js
const currentCETTime = moment.tz('2020-03-18 15:58:38', 'Europe/Madrid');
const limitCETTime = moment.tz('2020-03-18 18:00:00', 'Europe/Madrid');
console.log('current',currentCETTime.format('HH:mm:ss'));
console.log('limit', limitCETTime.format('HH:mm:ss'));
const seconds = Math.abs(limitCETTime.diff(currentCETTime) / 1000);
console.log('hours', (seconds / 60) / 60);
const rem = moment(seconds * 1000);
console.log('diff', moment(rem).utc().format('HH:mm'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll see the issue if you print out the entire date of `rem`:

```js
const currentCETTime = moment.tz('2020-03-18 15:58:38', 'Europe/Madrid');
const limitCETTime = moment.tz('2020-03-18 18:00:00', 'Europe/Madrid');
console.log('current',currentCETTime.format('HH:mm:ss'));
console.log('limit', limitCETTime.format('HH:mm:ss'));
const seconds = Math.abs(limitCETTime.diff(currentCETTime) / 1000);
console.log('hours', (seconds / 60) / 60);
const rem = moment(seconds * 1000);
console.log('diff', moment(rem).tz('Europe/Madrid').toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.min.js"></script>
```

Calling `moment` on a milliseconds value results in a new date from the epoch.

The difference in seconds is correct. If you want the difference in hours, you could call `diff` with the hours argument. Note that moment rounds down to the nearest whole value.

```js
const currentCETTime = moment.tz('2020-03-18 15:58:38', 'Europe/Madrid');
const limitCETTime = moment.tz('2020-03-18 18:00:00', 'Europe/Madrid');
console.log('current',currentCETTime.format('HH:mm:ss'));
console.log('limit', limitCETTime.format('HH:mm:ss'));
const hours = limitCETTime.diff(currentCETTime, 'hours');
console.log('hours', hours);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`moment(milliseconds)`, and also the tz variant, add the milliseconds to the date `1970-01-01 01:00:00`. This is is the [unix timestamp parser](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) behavior for this method. That is why, when formatted, it returns what *seems* like an extra hour but that is because it starts at hour 1 and not 0. You can check this behavior by passing in `0` for the total milliseconds and you will see that it returns hour value of 1.